# Unable to login as admin in PrestaShop

Tags: authentication, admin, prestashop

I have PrestaShop version 1.6.0.6 and have problem with log into admin panel for 2 weeks. I had not update any module or shop.

When I enter the correct e-mail and password it redirect me to the controller AdminDashboard, but quickly moved to AdminLogin by 302 redirect.

What should I check? What could it be? I have attached screenshot after login:

[image]

Comment: Enable debug mode to get more information and tell us if you encounter any error messages in the request response. check `preserve log` & `Doc` in the network console.

Comment: You can check the ajax-tab.php ajax response there you can get the errors if they exist

Comment: Same Problem did you not figured out ?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue you have to change `PS_CIPHER_ALGORITHM` in configuration table in database from 1 to 0 .

Comment: This one worked for me. I had tried resetting the password by hand and editing the isLoggedBack() metod at classes/Cookie.php

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try the following solution and let us know if it works for you.

It might be the issue because of login.php and init.php file. These two files are present in Admin folder and are responsible for validating the admin’s credentials. So, when these files send or get a cookie to/from the browser they get wrong the wrong path.

init.php

```
$cookie = new Cookie(‘psAdmin’, substr($_SERVER[‘SCRIPT_NAME’], strlen(PS_BASE_URI), -strlen($currentFileName[‘0’])));
```

login.php

```
 $cookie = new Cookie(‘psAdmin’, substr($_SERVER[‘PHP_SELF’],       strlen(PS_BASE_URI), -10));
```

These lines are not sending the correct path to the browser. Please try to use sites other than the main site as virtuals home pages as shown below.

login.php

```
$cookie = new Cookie(‘psAdmin’, “admin445” );
```

init.php

```
$cookie = new Cookie(‘psAdmin’, “admin445”);
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happens from time to time, you need to reconnect tried emptying its cache and cookies browsers, then try again.

Arthur